# Inherit backgroundpath when declaring new shape in PGF/TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am trying to create some basic optic elements (a beam splitter in this case) to be used in PGF/TikZ. Well, since I am quite new to PGF/TikZ (and even LaTeX), there is something I am not quite sure. The shape I want to create is almost as same as the predefined rectangle shape, except including an extra diagonal. My question is could I just append some code to the backgroudpath inherited from the predefined shape while not overwrite them, rather than copying all the predefined backgroundpath code together with my appending code?

Although I got some ideas from the example on page 631 in pgfmanual version 2.10. The shape I already created seemed working fine

[image]

The code I am using is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}    % pgfcore, modules shapes and plot
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{bs}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]

  \inheritbehindbackgroundpath[from=rectangle]
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=rectangle]
  \inheritbeforebackgroundpath[from=rectangle]
  \inheritbehindforegroundpath[from=rectangle]
  \inheritforegroundpath[from=rectangle]
  \inheritbeforeforegroundpath[from=rectangle]  
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}  

  \backgroundpath{
    % store lower left in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y        
    % construct main path
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathclose   
    % add diagonal
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
}   
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
  \node[shape=bs,draw,minimum size=1cm,label=below:BS] (x) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However if I try to remove the code for constructing rectangle and only leaving the diagonal code in `\backgroundpath{}` environment. I got a shape like following. It seemed this action has overwritten the inherited backgroundpath.

[image]

The code for above shape is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}    % pgfcore, modules shapes and plot
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{bs}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]

  \inheritbehindbackgroundpath[from=rectangle]
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=rectangle]
  \inheritbeforebackgroundpath[from=rectangle]
  \inheritbehindforegroundpath[from=rectangle]
  \inheritforegroundpath[from=rectangle]
  \inheritbeforeforegroundpath[from=rectangle]  
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}  

  \backgroundpath{
    % store lower left in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y        
    % construct main path
    %\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    %\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    %\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    %\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    %\pgfpathclose  
    % add diagonal
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
}   
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
  \node[shape=bs,draw,minimum size=1cm,label=below:BS] (x) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Since Till Tantau said the code for the shape rectangle may be quite complicated in reality (and thus may be more stable, fast and flexible?), so that is why I try to inherit the original backgroundpath with my extra diagonal code appended. Any suggestions or help will be truly appreciated:)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should like like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyone.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the suggestion. I just modified the post to include a MWE.

Comment: Just in case you want to draw more complex optical setups: [`pst-optexp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-optexp).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `\backgroundpath` is used in a shape definition it will overwrite any previous background-path specification inherited or otherwise.

The actual code for the rectangle background path is:

```
\pgfpathrectanglecorners
{\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}
    {\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}
```

Which looks a bit unfriendly but is simply taking into account the value of the `outer xsep` and `outer ysep` keys.

The code could be copy/pasted into the `\backgroundpath` code for a new shape or the internal command `\pgf@sh@bg@rectangle` could be used (it contains the code for background path for the rectangle).

Either way the proposed additional diagonal would also have to take into account the `outer sep`. I think a possibly more efficient way (i.e., less calls to the `PGF` mathematical engine) for doing the whole thing would be:

```
\pgfextract@process\outersep{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
  {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}%
\pgfextract@process\southwest{\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\outersep}}%
\pgfextract@process\northeast{\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\outersep}}}%
\pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\southwest}%
\pgfpathlineto{\northeast}%
```

Comment: Dear Mark, thank you so much for your detailed explanation.I replaced my backgroundpath with your code and it works perfectly now (I guess it must be more efficient and flexible).Also I got some idea about PGF/TikZ programming manner from you answer:) Though I did not find how to reward your answer here, please let me know how to make it if possible. BTW, did you dig into the particular library/package to find the \backgroundpath code for rectangle? I didn't find them on the PGF/TikZ manual. Thanks~

Comment: The code for the rectangle (and circle) is in `pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex`. The rest of the shapes are in the files that start with `pgflibraryshapes`.